# C# Type object as payload to Post Method

Tags: c#

Can we upload a C# Type object to a Post Method ?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("SendModelPayload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendModelPayload([FromBody] Type type)
    {
        // Do some stuff
        return Ok("test");
    }
```

But, Here type is null.

client code:

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://localhost:5000");

        var res = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(@"/api/ModelPayload/SendModelPayload", 
        typeof(Student)).Result;
```

Any ideas, Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Do you want to upload the type (`typeof(Student)`) or an actual instance of that type (`new Student()`)? 
What are you trying to achieve by sending the `Type`?

Comment: what's the data type for `typeof(Student)).Result`?

Comment: Hi, CodexNZ, I will use Type variable for deserializing the binary data uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When transmitting data to a REST API, you need to keep in mind that client and server are basically unrelated in terms of technology and therefore use a common ground that a lot of programming languages support. In your case, there might be a .NET client and a .NET server, but it could well be that a Javascript client calls your API that does not know of the `Type` class. Even if you have .NET client and a .NET server, the client could send a type that the server is unaware of.

So you need to find a common ground that is supported by various programming environments and is flexible enough to also cope with the situation that the client sends data that the server cannot map to a type.

One way would be to not transmit a `Type` directly, but transmit the type name as a string. The server could then try to load the type directly. If the type can be found, it could work with the type, if not, it would return a `BadRequestResult` to notify the client of the invalid data.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("SendModelPayload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendModelPayload([FromBody] string typeName)
{
    // Try to load type
    var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
    if (type == null)
        return BadRequest();
    // Do some stuff
    return Ok("test");
}
```

The client would send a type name instead of a real type e.g.

```
var res = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(@"/api/ModelPayload/SendModelPayload", 
    typeof(Student).AssemblyQualifiedName).Result;
```

By transmitting the `AssemblyQualifiedName`, the type name is very specific, so the server needs to be able to load the exact same type, but fail if it cannot laod the type.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you want to upload a `Student` instance to the `SendModelPayload` endpoint?

If that is correct, then a couple of changes are necessary to get what you have working:

#### POST Method

```cs
    // changed to accept Student object in body
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("SendModelPayload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SendModelPayload([FromBody] Student type)
    {
        // Do some stuff
        return Ok("test");
    }
```

#### Client Code

```cs
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://localhost:5000");

    // create instance and populate it with data
    var studentInstance = new Student() { Name = "Student Name" };

    // then call the post method and pass the instance of the Student class
    // that will get serialized and sent as the body
    var res = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(@"/api/ModelPayload/SendModelPayload", 
        studentInstance).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Expecting TYPE from body. Convert string input to Type

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("SendModelPayload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendModelPayload([FromBody] string TypeName)
{
var ty = Type.GetType(TypeName);
if(ty != null)
```

Suggesting as I am not exactly aware with requirement